# chisq.test: x and y must have the same length

Tags: r

Well I'm pretty sure about that in chi square test, we need have all arguments in the same length. The key is, my vector x and y do have the same length.

I have a very biased data. x: 499 1; with the expected probability y: 0.998 0.002;
I'm sure that the length for x and y are both 2.

```
> y <- c(0.998,0.002)
> x <- c(499,1)
> chisq.test(x,p=y)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

Warning message:
In chisq.test(x, p = y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> chisq.test(x,p=y,simulate.p.value = T,rescale.p = T,2000)
Error in chisq.test(x, p = y, simulate.p.value = T, rescale.p = T, 2000) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Is there any critical line for the original data. I know that chi-square require the expected counts in each cell is over 5. But what I have is just like this, how can I deal with it.
This is not a single test, but a step in my circulation, I have to deal with this "special case".

Thank you so much if you could do me a favor.

Comment: Maybe you need to name the last parameter - try `B=2000` instead

Comment: Cool, thank you! I didn't notice this detail! I feel so silly.